# I need to know how many combinations are possible from these, if I must select at least one (but can choose more than one) from each table

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

I have a very simple permutation question that I can't figure out on my own.
So, I have

```
{A, B, C}
```

and

```
{D, E, F}
```

I need to know how many combinations are possible from these, if I must select at least one (but can choose more than one) from each table. For example, it could be `(A,D), (AB,D), (ABC,D), (A,DEF)`, etc. (Note that, `(AB,D)` would mean the same thing as `(BA,D)`.)

For `{A,B} {C,D}`, I know it is 9 because I manually wrote all of the possible combinations but I get stuck if its higher than 3,4.

I am trying to figure this out because although I have written code that incorporates all of the combinations I am not sure how many combinations there are. How do you solve this?

The actual tables have:

2 entries, 2 entries, 8 entries, 2 entries, 11 entries respectively.
Once I figure out the basics, I will try to apply that on the actual tables.

Comment: You ask about combinations or permutations?

Comment: As @Tim said, you should clarify whether the order of the selections matter - is "ABC" different to "BAC"?

Comment: Are combinations like (A,D,B) or (AE,C) allowed?

Comment: @Silverfish No, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @RustyStatistician yea but (A,D,B) would be considered the same thing as (A,B,D) or (D,B,A)

Comment: @AccessExcelVBA, thanks, you should edit that detail into your question so that everyone can see it rather than clarifying it in the comments. When you're editing, can you make clear whether the question is self-study or whether it arose in a practical situation - if the latter, then it might help if you could sketch some details of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. An additional question... you seem to allow selecting multiple entries from a table, e.g. `(AB, E)` but what about selecting nothing from one or both tables? Is `(A,)`  or `(,E)` or plain `(,)` allowed?

Comment: @Silverfish Oh, Sorry. At least one has to be selected from a table. So (A,) wouldnt give out anything. Neither will (,)

Comment: @AccessExcelVBA I suggest you rewrite "I need to know how many combinations are possible from these It could have more than one from each table" to "I need to know how many combinations are possible from these, if I must select at least one (but can choose more than one) from each table." I think that'd clarify things considerably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're taking a non-empty subset of each set. If a set has $n$ elements, then the number of subsets equals $\binom n0 + \binom n1 + ... + \binom nn = 2^n$.

(If you're not familiar with this formula, consider that each element can be "in" or "out" of the subset. So each element has two options, thus yielding $2^n$ possible subsets.)

But since you don't want the empty set you should subtract $1$ (since $\binom n0 = 1$). So the number of non-empty subsets of a given set with $n$ elements is $2^n - 1$.

Since your sets have, respectively, $2$, $2$, $8$, $2$, and $11$ elements, the total arrangements you're looking for is $(2^2-1)\cdot(2^2-1)\cdot (2^8-1) \cdot (2^{2} - 1) \cdot (2^{11} - 1)$.

If you have sets with $n_1, n_2, n_3,\ldots n_i$ elements, then you would have $$(2^{n_1}-1)\cdot (2^{n_2}-1) \cdots (2^{n_i}-1)$$ combinations.

Comment: You've forgotten ABCD.

Comment: In your solution, does the order matter? In my case, the order shouldn't matter and they are considered equal.

Comment: No, order doesn't matter. The $2^n$ subsets of a set with $n$ elements is the number of subsets without regard to order.